# Issue in webdav on mac machine

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

A user with permission to create folders and components is not able to copy and paste items through WebDAV. This User is using Mac OS X Lion. The error he gets is that he does not have read and write permissions. Is there any resolution?

Comment: It's fairly important to know the exact error message he gets, and which system it is coming from. For instance: is there an error in the Event Log from Tridion when he attempts to create a Folder?

Comment: Copy where? From one WebDAV folder to another or from WebDAV to your PC, or vice versa?

Comment: We have given the permissions which are working fine on windows OS but issue is only with Mac Os. The error is that user is don't have read and write access. User is copying from PC to webdav folder.

Answer (score 1):

The WebDAV Connector is enabled by default server-side per [the SDLLiveContent documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_2E6D8CF0561142D0B81B8CE11DD72BD2) at least for SDL Tridion 2011.

Only valid items are allowed via WebDAV which includes binaries (multimedia in Tridion), .xml components, and other types.

It seems like the user doesn't have permissions to read and write for a given folder. You can confirm by having them attempt creating folders or components in the same folder in the Content Manager Explorer (CME).

Comment: We have given the permissions which are working fine on windows OS but issue is only with Mac Os. The error is that user is don't have read and write access. User is copying from PC to webdav folder.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the Mac does not authenticate properly to Windows. In this case, you should be able to see the failed connections in your server logs. Is this user (or any other Mac user) able to use webdav successfully in any other folders?

Answer (score 1):

As it's been suggested already, you will have to do some detective work to determine what exactly is failing. Tridion permissions do not change based on the client you use, so if they work from one client, they must work from another (excluding authentication issues here).

- Go to your Windows Event Viewer, Tridion Content Manager log, check for error messages written to it when you try to copy content from the mac.
- Post the *exact* error message you're getting. I doubt that Tridion is telling you "user is don't have read and write access"

Bottom line, if it works from Windows and not Mac, the issue is not with the WebDav server, but with the WebDav Client.

I also fail to see the programming question on this one...

Answer (score 0):

What version of Tridion are you using? First action which you should do is to check Event Log for error messages (it was already suggested by Peter Kjaer), if you don't have anything there you can try to enable webdav debug logging by modifying cc_crtd_def.xml file which is situated in Tridion\webdav\WebDAVcartridges\Default\ folder. You should change loglevel property (as far as I remember it should be 4 for debug). And then there should be a log file created in the same folder or in webdav folder. You can try to find exact error message in this log file and post it here.